# Кэширование страницы в devmode GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Имеется обычный проект на GWT. После изменения html-страницы и java-кода я делаю пере сборку проекта и запускаю отладочный сервер (devmode). При отображении в обозревателе страница имеет след. ссылку

> http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Когда страница загружается, я вижу не новую старую, а старую. Как я понял, это из за кэширования страницы. Как убрать это кэширование?

Процесс сборки такой:

```
ant clean
ant build
ant devmode
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменения в java-коде должны точно применяться при пересборке. Если же речь о самих страницах, то всё как обычно: либо выключить кэш в браузере, либо жать Ctrl-F5 для принудительной перезагрузки. Сам GWT-shell не кэширует страницы.

Comment: Думаю, там все сложнее. Код пересобираю из консоли. Обновление страницы в обозревателе ничего не дает. Помогает лишь удаление доп параметров в ссылке - http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html .

Comment: Так вы сам шелл перезапускаете?

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой.
Вот ант-скрипт для запуска dev-mode. Пересборку проекта делать не надо! F5 и всё.

структура папок

```
../src - исходники гвт
../web
      /ru.seemap.gwt.main.SeeMap/
      /temp/index.html
      /WEB-INF/
```

пс. работающий скрипт сайта www.seemap.ru

```
<target name="devmode-main">
        <delete dir="web/ru.seemap.gwt.main.SeeMap"/>
        <antcall target="run.devmode">
            <param name="gwt.war" value="web"/>
            <param name="gwt.startup.url" value="temp/index.html"/>
            <param name="gwt.module.name" value="ru.seemap.gwt.main.SeeMap"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

<target name="run.devmode" depends="compile" description="Run development mode">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="src"/>
                <path refid="common_library"/>
                <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
            </classpath>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
            <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.startup.url}"/>
            <arg value="-war"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.war}"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.module.name}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил так: Когда запускается встроенный сервер (devmode), нажимаем "посмотреть в обозревателе по умолчанию", после открытия обозревателя, идем на сервер и на вкладке "Jetty" нажимаем "перезагрузить сервер".